# iOS "Restore Purchase" button and InAppBillingPlugin

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I have in-app Non-Consumable product in my app. This is Xamarin.Forms and I use InAppBillingPlugin.

When I load the app, I check if product is purchased, and app acts accordingly, indicating if purchase was made. However, Apple insists on having "Restore Purchase" button.

Can anyone help me understand this requirement. Should this button always be enabled? What exactly should happen if it's clicked, same code as "Buy Product", or something else? Specifically, what method of this plugin should be called?

Comment: In iOS which product user purchases is binding to user's Apple account. So if a user delete the app without a backup and download it again. We need to help him restore the products which he has purchased before. Not let him buy again. This is the difference between "buy" and "restore".

Comment: I understand that, but I kind of do it automatically when I load the app. I don't store the purchase anywhere (am I doing it wrong?). So, I don't understand the purpose of button. Anyway, I added the button which kind of does nothing (repeats same thing I do on loading app), and passed certification.